# Why styles sometimes don't apply when using sass in nextjs

Tags: next.js

When using SASS in NEXTJS, sometimes the styling works and sometimes it doesn't.
When this happens, I restart the server and the styles work fine.
Why are these bugs happening?
I didn't have this bug in react.